# Why is $\binom{k}{2}$ + $\binom{n−k}{2}$ maximized when $k = 1$ or $k = n - 1$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs

I was looking at another answer on this stack exchange

"An alternate proof strategy: if $G$
is the disconnected union of a $k$
-vertex graph and an $(n−k)$
-vertex graph, then it has at most
$\binom{k}{2}$ + $\binom{n−k}{2}$
edges; this is maximized when $k=1$
or $k=n−1$
, in which case the bound on the number of edges is $(n−1)(n−2)2$"

and I know it truly is maximized when $k=1$ or $k=n-1$ but I was hoping to get an analytical or combinatorial proof as to why?
.

Comment: A necessary condition for the maximizer $k$ is that $f(k)\geq f(k+1)$ and $f(k)\geq f(k-1)$ if $f$ denotes your expression and sometimes this is enough to single out one value.

Answer (score 3):

The function $f(k):={k\choose 2}+{n-k\choose 2}$ is quadratic in $k$. It's a parabola opening up, with vertex at $k=\frac n2$. You can see this by expanding out the binomial coefficients and then taking a derivative (or completing the square). So $f(k)$ is maximized when $k$ is farthest from $\frac n2$. Since we exclude the degenerate cases $k=0$ and $k=n$, the maximum occurs at the next furthest values $k=1$ and $k=n-1$. You can check that these two values for $k$ are equidistant from $\frac n2$.